# Spring's @Value annotation is being ignored in dependent .jar when referenced from a .war

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jar, war

**SETUP**:

At our company we run multiple sites (many .war files deployed in a single TomCat server).  However, most of the .WAR files are identical in the .classes that they use.  So we refactored the common classes in to a separate .jar which was then included in each of the .wars.

Now, realizing that all the .war(s) include the same .jar, we decided to further reduce the size of the .war files by removing the duplicated .jar and adding it to the shared.loader in catalina.properties (we are using Tomcat 7).

We left the .war files to only contain configurations specific to each site's configuration.

We are using Spring to help us with wiring classes together.

**PROBLEM**:

Some classes in the newly refactored .jar file contain @Value annotation.  It appears that the @Value annotation is not being "executed" and the value being annotated is never set.  If we add the .jar file back into the .war the annotation works and value is set.  However, just pulling the .jar out into the shared.loader class path fails to process the @Value annotations.

Interestingly the @Component annotations work fine and the relationships are properly @Autowired, it just that all the @Value annotated fields are null.  We are using Sprin 3.1.4.

We are using Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to read the property file.  The confirurer is created by the applicationContext.xml referenced from the .war.

**QUESTION**:

Is there a way to fix this while continuing to have the .jar file external to the .war file that depends on it?

**CONFIGURATION**

Here is the configuration that lives in the .war file.  The common .jar file does not have any configuration files:

```
applicationContext.xml:
    -----------------------
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="config" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
            <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Scan for components in .jar -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.usamp.gozing.comm.service" />

    <!-- Scan for components in the .war -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc.rest" />
</beans>
```

Here is the application.properties:

```
application.hostname="test1eeee33332342341234:-in war"
workflow.rule.name="matched workflow - in war"
```

The configuration is bootstrapped, by standard web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Dynamic ApplicationContext</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.springapp.mvc.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks.

-AP_

Comment: Could you paste your spring configuration?

Comment: The applicationContext.xml is in the .WAR file, it loads the properties and performs two component scans.  The first scan scans the common .jar, the second scan scans the classes in the .war.

Comment: I added the configuration to the main message.